# Plugin Submenu Admin

Tags: php, plugins, impresspages

How do you create Submenu items for a plugin.

I've checked System Module, That have Submenu class, and Filter on Admin. Is this possible without hacking or Overriding class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can.

Layout response object has method 'setLayoutVariable'. One of accepted variables is 'submenu'. If you supply an array of Ip\Menu\Item objects, a submenu will be generated. Here is an example. Put it in Plugin\Application\Event.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Plugin\Application;


class Event
{
    public static function ipBeforeController()
    {

        if (true) { //find out some kind of a condition when you want a submenu. (eg. ipRequest()->getControllerClass() == 'Plugin\XXX\AdminController')
            $submenu = array();
            $submenuItem = new \Ip\Menu\Item();
            $submenuItem->setTitle('Test');
            $submenuItem->setUrl('http://www.example.com');
            $submenu[] = $submenuItem;

            if (is_object(ipResponse()) && method_exists(ipResponse(), 'setLayoutVariable')) {
                ipResponse()->setLayoutVariable('submenu', $submenu);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

You can filter main menu too using filter. Add following code to Plugin\Application\Filter.php file:

```
<?php

namespace Plugin\Application;


class Filter {
    /**
     * @param \Ip\Menu\Item[] $menu
     * @param $info
     */
    public static function ipAdminMenu ($menu, $info)
    {
        //modify $menu

        return $menu;
    }
}
```